# How to convert an Image SRC URL to Base64 using apex?

Tags: apex, attachment

https://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo11w.png

I have a URL ,something like above coming from third party external website through REST API.I need to  convert these URL to base 64 encoded format .How would i achieve this using only through apex without using javascript to get base 64 encoded string from this URL?

Comment: You mean to a [Data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) right?

Comment: yes .The data URL is returned .For example sites like Linked In dont return base 64 encoded data and they return only There Photo URL

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
public class ImageUri {
    public static String getDataUriFromUri(String url) {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(url);
        req.setMethod('GET');
        Http binding = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = binding.send(req);
        Blob image = res.getBodyAsBlob();
        return 'data:'+res.getHeader('Content-Type')+';base64,'+EncodingUtil.base64Encode(image);
    }
}
```

Be sure to authorize the endpoint in Setup > Security Controls > Remote Site Settings.

Example output:

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```

Comment: I owe you a drink at next Dreamforce 